# Nested FirestoreRecyclerAdapter Shows Nothing

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

I'm trying to achieve an Instagram style comment section. I have a collection group query /comments and can display comments just fine with RecyclerView.
Inside of the parent FirestoreRecyclerAdapter onBindViewHolder I have this.

```
           DocumentSnapshot snapshot = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            String commentId = snapshot.getId();
            System.out.println("[CommentID: ]" + commentId);

            Query rQuery = mFirestore.collectionGroup("comments")
                    .whereEqualTo("postId", commentId)
                    .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                    .limit(50);

            FirestoreRecyclerOptions<SubCommentModel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<SubCommentModel>()
                    .setQuery(rQuery, SubCommentModel.class).build();

            RecyclerView replyRecycler = holder.reply_recycler;

            rAdapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<SubCommentModel, ReplyTypeViewHolder>(options) {
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ReplyTypeViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull SubCommentModel model) {
                    final SimpleDateFormat FORMAT  = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US);

                    ((ReplyTypeViewHolder) holder).author_name.setText(model.getAuthor());
                    ((ReplyTypeViewHolder) holder).comment_text.setText(model.getComment());
                    ((ReplyTypeViewHolder) holder).time_stamp.setText(FORMAT.format(model.getTimestamp()));
                }

                @NonNull
                @Override
                public ReplyTypeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                    View view;
                    view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.comment_item, parent, false);
                    return new ReplyTypeViewHolder(view);
                }
```

Outside of this block, I set replyRecycler to the nested adapter; I set up Linear Layout Manager and start listening.

However this does nothing. In fact doing addSnapShotLinstener to cQuery returns nothing. No error and no data.

Comment: where you see nothing happening, on the frontend tring to display this? or yo refer to not getting the data from firestore?

Comment: Both actually. There's nothing on the frontend and when I do cQuery.addSnapshotListener I get neither error nor data.